# Using whereIn and where in Laravel eloquent query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-in

I have been trying to do a query with laravel eloquent query builder but without success.

This is what I want to achieve: I have a webshop with laptops. People can search by brand, screen diameter and processor. My table is called 'laptops' with columns 'specsTag', 'screen_diameter' and 'processor'.
I'm using checkboxes. So the request is an array and may look like

```
['HP','Apple', '12 inch', 'Intel Core M']
```

First I want to get all brands in the array as a collection and filter them accordingly using the values in the array.

I tried several things. I.e. trying to search on screen diameter.

Suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$laptops = Laptop::whereIn('specsTag',$requestArray)->where(function($query) use ($requestArray){
                foreach($requestArray as $item){
                    $query->orWhere('screen_diameter','=',$item);
                }
            })->get();
```

Assuming you have `$requestArray` like this

```
$requestArray = ['HP','Apple' '12 inch', 'Intel Core M'];
```

You will get sql like this

```
select * from `laptops` where `specsTag` in (?, ?, ?, ?) and (`screen_diameter` = ? or `screen_diameter` = ? or `screen_diameter` = ? or `screen_diameter` = ?)
```

Comment: This is working nicely. Thank you! This is my working code:

Comment: { $laptops = Laptop::whereIn('specsTag',$brands)->where(function($query) use ($screen_diameter){

            foreach($screen_diameter as $diameter){
                $query->Orwhere('screen_diameter','=',$diameter);
            }})->where(function($query) use ($pro_cessor){

           foreach($pro_cessor as $pro){
                $query->Orwhere('processor','=',$pro);
            } })->get();}

Answer (score 0):

This is my latest try:

```
$laptops = Laptop::whereIn('specsTag',$requestArray)->where('screen_diameter', function($query) use ($requestArray)
        {
            foreach($requestArray as $item){
                $query->where('screen_diameter','=',$item,'or');
            }
})->get();

I'm getting an error from my DB:
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select * from `laptops` where `specsTag` in (ASUS, 12 inch) and `screen_diameter` = (select * where `screen_diameter` = ASUS or `screen_diameter` = 12 inch)) ◀"
```